# Display issues using docking station Dell Universal 6000

Tags: macos, display, dock

I bought a Dell Universal 6000 docking station for my MacBook Pro 2018 to plug in 3 monitors via one Thunderbolt. The problem is that after installing DisplayLink drivers, only 2 displays are useable, both on DisplayPorts, but when I unplug one of them, the display on the HDMI port appears, so it seems like only two of them can be active at the same time. Some time ago when I was almost done fighting with it, I ran an update which popped up few days later and after that it started working. Yesterday I also ran some updates and have this issue again.

I have some suspicions that maybe this GateKeeper update is blocking it there.

Any help appreciated because after hours spent before computer I still cannot solve this issue.

Computer: MacBook Pro 2018

Docking station: Dell Universal 6000

macOS: Mojave 10.14.4

DisplayLink driver: 5.0 (also tried 5.1)

[image]